# How do I make Conan generate CMake Find scripts for CMake OBJECT libraries?

Tags: c, cmake, conan

I'm creating CMake OBJECT libraries which I need to combine later into a single SDK library.

I can install the files and package them with Conan.

```
add_library(mylib_OBJECTS OBJECT
   # ...
```

```
install(TARGETS mylib mylib_OBJECTS
    # object libraries
    OBJECTS DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

This makes cmake install the object libraries like this:

```
├── conaninfo.txt
├── conanmanifest.txt
└── lib
    ├── libmylib.a
    └── objects-Release
        └── mylib_OBJECTS
            ├── aio.o
            ├── atomic.o
            ├── bitmap.o
```

What `cpp_info` should I set to make Conan aware of that object library, and generate the correct FindMyLib.cmake file for it?

Comment: Conan does not model explicitly object libraries. While it is possible to package objects, the consumption might probably be manual for most build systems. There is some discussion here https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/5159 and https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/8703. I'd recommend commenting on those issues to push this feature.

Comment: @drodri, thanks for the information. I don't think either of those tickets addresses exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, so I opened a new ticket.
https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/9438